# Warning when building an Angular app with Ahead-of-time compilation

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I'm using angular-cli for a recent project. Building for development works as expected, however building for production with `ng build --prod` outputs the following warning:

> WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 
>   498:95-110 "export 'string' (imported as 'import34') was not found in
>   '../../app/api.service'

As a result, the application won't run. Thanks to a comment by R. Richards it turned out that this warning is caused by the Ahead-of-time compilation that is done when building for production with angular-cli.

My ApiService looks like this:

```
import {Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams, RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions,
  RequestMethod
} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Item} from './models/item';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional() protected basePath: string)       {
      if (basePath) {
          this.basePath = basePath;
      }
      this.http = http;
    }

    //...
}
```

Investigating this in more detail shows that this warning is caused by the optional dependency injection (`@Optional() protected basePath: string`). Removing it results in a warning-free build with a running application.

Comment: looks like error is something else , not in this file, will you please post full error message ?

Comment: @PardeepJain It's not an error; just a warning. Does the application work?

Comment: This is the entire warning. The application doesn't work in production. There is an error regarding a missing token.

Comment: opps yes i mean warning , my misspelling ;)

Comment: Something to look into: I *think* that the build process uses AOT by default. You may want to look into seeing if there is a way to turn this off. Maybe the app will work without it(?).

Comment: Good point, I'll give it a try and update the post. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the @Optional() as well, and the warning disappears. This warning leads to an unusable application if the service is called. I guess, that the @Optional and AOT are not working together really well. Looks like a problem with polyfills to me.